# CCNode with children properties and actions

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm pretty new to cocos2d development and ran into a problem of getting a valid `boundingBox` and `contentSize`, and running `CCAction`s on `CCNode`s with children. It seemed to me that if your `CCNode` has children and you call `boundingBox` (for example) on that `CCNode`, you should get a `CGRect` of that `CCNode` that takes into account its children. Or is it that I'm just organizing my code incorrectly..?

Anyway, I've written a small category for `CCNode` that seems to return the correct `boundingBox` and `contentSize` and runs actions on its children.

```
@implementation CCNode(Children)

- (CGRect)boundingBoxC {
    if (self.boundingBox.size.width != 0 || self.boundingBox.size.height != 0) {
        return self.boundingBox;
    }

    CGRect holderRect = CGRectZero;

    for (int i = 0; i < self.children.count; i++) {
        CCNode *node = [self.children objectAtIndex:i];
        holderRect = CGRectUnion(holderRect, node.boundingBoxC);
    }

    return holderRect;
}

- (CGSize)contentSizeC {
    return self.boundingBoxC.size;
}

- (void)runActionC:(CCAction *)action {
    [self runAction:action];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.children.count; i++) {
        id action2 = [action copy];
        CCNode *node = [self.children objectAtIndex:i];
        [node runActionC:action2];
        [actions2 release];
    }
}

@end
```

I'd love to get some feedback on this. For example, I started by trying to use the name `boundingBox` instead of `boundingBoxC`, but wasn't confident that that was good practice (it involved swizzling). Or if there's a more comprehensive, elegant solution to this, I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, in your runActionC:, wouldn't that be a memory leak? you're copying without releasing

Comment: @XSlash, thanks for the heads up. I've modified the code to include the `release`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of nodes as reference points, not boxes, and you can see why the default behaviour is as it is. Your code looks clean (and glad to see it's in a category rather than a subclass!) and I can't see any problems with your logic. Definitely don't override built-in methods (unless you really need to), as 1) you could create conflicts and 2) future developers will be confused.